# Reputation display update keeps displaying bug

Tags: bug

The same reputation update keeps displaying no matter how times I dismiss it. Its quite irritating. Can it be stopped?

Comment: Same here as well.

Comment: The same thing happened for an inbox message for a comment I had this morning. It made the icon light up several times even though I already read it, but it eventually stopped.

Comment: Also, the reputation gains on Meta_SO are behind SO by the number of highlights on SO.